# sorted関数の引数について

Tags: python, python3

プログラミング初心者です。
以下のコードで、sorted関数の引数keyでget_ageを指定しています。
このときget_age関数の引数が明示されていませんが、これはdataの要素が引数になっているという解釈で良いでしょうか？

```
data = [('Alice', 15), ('Bob', 21), ('Carol', 23)]

def get_age(item):
    return item[1]

data = sorted(data, key=get_age)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 短い答え

はい。

## 長い答え

`sorted` 関数のリファレンスを読んでみましょう。

> key には 1 引数関数を指定します。これは iterable の各要素から比較キーを展開するのに使われます (例えば、 key=str.lower のように指定します)。 デフォルト値は None です (要素を直接比較します)。
>   [組み込み関数 — Python 3.8.0 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

と記載されている通り、 1引数関数である `get_age` が指定されています。このため、`sorted` は最初に渡された `iterable` の各要素を `get_age` に渡していきます。

そして、 `get_age` が返す値（ここでは各要素の2番目の値、すなわち `15` 、 `21` 、 `23` ）を `sorted` が比較することでソートを行います。